# Microsoft Access user log of form open

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a Microsoft access database with sql backend. I need a log of windows users with date and time who successfully open a form. I prefer to have the data recorded to a linked sql server table. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the Windows Username:

```vb
Environ("username")
```

This will get you the Date & Time:

```vb
Now()
```

I would suggest defining a function in a Public Module such as:

```vb
Function winuser() As String
    winuser = Environ("username")
End Function
```

And then using the following SQL to insert records into your log table:

```sql
insert into log ([username], [timestamp]) values (winuser(), now())
```

Change `log`, `username` & `timestamp` to the names of your table & fields.

This SQL could then be executed as part of the `On Open` event for the form.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum for Lee Macs answer:

For security reasons you should use

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Network").UserName
```

instead of

```
Environ("username")
```

to retrieve to current logged in Windows user because the environment variable `username` can easily be overwritten (means someone could pretend a different user).

Alternatively, if you prefer, you also can use the Windows API:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Public Function GetWindowsUserName() As String
    Dim buffer As String * 255

    Dim result As Long
    result = GetUserName(buffer, 255)

    If result > 0 Then _
        GetWindowsUserName = Left(buffer, InStr(buffer, Chr(0)) - 1)
End Function
```